# podman pod in inconsistent state and can't be deleted

Tags: linux

At some point in the past, removing a pod with podman failed and now I have an inconsistent state which I don't know how to fix. Apparently the storage for the infra container was deleted on disk, but podman still believes the container exists. I have one of these for my root instance as well as rootless. Please help me figure out how to clean this up (remove the reference to this pod which no longer exists and nuke the infra container as well...)

The host system is Fedora 29 Silverblue.

podman output...

```
[bnordgren@brycelap ~]$ podman pod ls
POD ID         NAME   STATUS    CREATED       # OF CONTAINERS   INFRA ID
e61ac0328400   test   Created   4 weeks ago   1                 31770c3e3fda
[bnordgren@brycelap ~]$ podman ps -a
CONTAINER ID  IMAGE                 COMMAND  CREATED      STATUS   PORTS  NAMES
31770c3e3fda  k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.1           4 weeks ago  Created         e61ac0328400-infra
[bnordgren@brycelap ~]$ podman --log-level debug pod rm -f e61
INFO[0000] running as rootless                          
DEBU[0000] Initializing boltdb state at /var/home/bnordgren/.local/share/containers/storage/libpod/bolt_state.db 
DEBU[0000] Using graph driver overlay                   
DEBU[0000] Using graph root /var/home/bnordgren/.local/share/containers/storage 
DEBU[0000] Using run root /run/user/1000                
DEBU[0000] Using static dir /var/home/bnordgren/.local/share/containers/storage/libpod 
DEBU[0000] Using tmp dir /run/user/1000/libpod/tmp      
DEBU[0000] Using volume path /var/home/bnordgren/.local/share/containers/storage/volumes 
DEBU[0000] Set libpod namespace to ""                   
DEBU[0000] Not configuring container store              
INFO[0000] running as rootless                          
WARN[0000] The configuration is using `runtime_path`, which is deprecated and will be removed in future.  Please use `runtimes` and `runtime` 
WARN[0000] If you are using both `runtime_path` and `runtime`, the configuration from `runtime_path` is used 
DEBU[0000] Initializing boltdb state at /var/home/bnordgren/.local/share/containers/storage/libpod/bolt_state.db 
DEBU[0000] Using graph driver overlay                   
DEBU[0000] Using graph root /var/home/bnordgren/.local/share/containers/storage 
DEBU[0000] Using run root /run/user/1000                
DEBU[0000] Using static dir /var/home/bnordgren/.local/share/containers/storage/libpod 
DEBU[0000] Using tmp dir /run/user/1000/libpod/tmp      
DEBU[0000] Using volume path /var/home/bnordgren/.local/share/containers/storage/volumes 
DEBU[0000] Set libpod namespace to ""                   
DEBU[0000] [graphdriver] trying provided driver "overlay" 
DEBU[0000] overlay: mount_program=/usr/bin/fuse-overlayfs 
DEBU[0000] backingFs=extfs, projectQuotaSupported=false, useNativeDiff=false, usingMetacopy=false 
DEBU[0000] Cleaning up container 31770c3e3fdabb91b2a8ccd2856a947782b5a6dcb02670efb4a39bb2a9773c74 
DEBU[0000] Network is already cleaned up, skipping...   
DEBU[0000] Storage is already unmounted, skipping...    
DEBU[0000] Storage is already unmounted, skipping...    
WARN[0000] Storage for container 31770c3e3fdabb91b2a8ccd2856a947782b5a6dcb02670efb4a39bb2a9773c74 already removed 
ERRO[0000] no such file or directory
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you don't want to remove `$HOME/.local/share/containers` outright, you'll need to edit some JSON files.

1. Shut down all `podman` containers if at all possible.
2. Look for the SHA256 entry in `$HOME/.local/share/containers/storage/overlay-containers/containers.json` You should see entries for each valid container in addition to the one that you're trying to fix.
3. Remove the complete entry corresponding to the SHA256 container you'd like podman to forget about.

Here's an example from my system, using `jq` to make things pretty. I currently have two podman containers: fcb8454b75ad / freedv, and 8456a27c0f4c / tang. If the freedv container 'disappeared' like yours did, I would remove the second section, including the comma following the closing brace of the first section, leaving the final closing square bracket:

```
  },  <-- Remove the comma but not the closing brace.
  {
    "id": "fcb8454b75ad8
...
      "ProcessLabel": ""
    }
  }  <-- Remove this.
]    <-- Leave this
```

Here's the complete file, before modifications:

```
[
  {
    "id": "8456a27c0f4c2d1492f45263b97b0e5e4f9a688e6aed26a2270f490b2be04155",
    "names": [
      "tang"
    ],
    "image": "9b21690ebd2027c33705ab485c699fb8f4c4d618b2e80294ee2041e8e7f3f840",
    "layer": "a8262df0b380a570868d5d6b619c62bec3b053ae7732810324dc594af3023a9e",
    "metadata": "{\"image-name\":\"docker.io/malaiwah/tang:latest\",\"image-id\":\"9b21690ebd2027c33705ab485c699fb8f4c4d618b2e80294ee2041e8e7f3f840\",\"name\":\"tang\",\"created-at\":1573364175}",
    "created": "2019-11-10T05:36:15.150718037Z",
    "flags": {
      "MountLabel": "system_u:object_r:container_file_t:s0:c158,c440",
      "ProcessLabel": "system_u:system_r:container_t:s0:c158,c440"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": "fcb8454b75ad8f2ff2b610e10b16067fdd94015e5166c78b771cc4732b706b98",
    "names": [
      "freedv"
    ],
    "image": "a198bc8c3cda783856295d4d4859668217afc4ffc6f79a171c896f1b13e5ed21",
    "layer": "9107cb88795602ce1507b39bc56e46f212e6d0a268fa467809d9d7b7d777ce75",
    "metadata": "{\"image-name\":\"registry.fedoraproject.org/f31/fedora-toolbox:31\",\"image-id\":\"a198bc8c3cda783856295d4d4859668217afc4ffc6f79a171c896f1b13e5ed21\",\"name\":\"freedv\",\"created-at\":1575051814}",
    "created": "2019-11-29T18:23:34.237852598Z",
    "flags": {
      "MountLabel": "system_u:object_r:container_file_t:s0:c662,c960",
      "ProcessLabel": ""
    }
  }
]
```

After modifications:

```
[
  {
    "id": "8456a27c0f4c2d1492f45263b97b0e5e4f9a688e6aed26a2270f490b2be04155",
    "names": [
      "tang"
    ],
    "image": "9b21690ebd2027c33705ab485c699fb8f4c4d618b2e80294ee2041e8e7f3f840",
    "layer": "a8262df0b380a570868d5d6b619c62bec3b053ae7732810324dc594af3023a9e",
    "metadata": "{\"image-name\":\"docker.io/malaiwah/tang:latest\",\"image-id\":\"9b21690ebd2027c33705ab485c699fb8f4c4d618b2e80294ee2041e8e7f3f840\",\"name\":\"tang\",\"created-at\":1573364175}",
    "created": "2019-11-10T05:36:15.150718037Z",
    "flags": {
      "MountLabel": "system_u:object_r:container_file_t:s0:c158,c440",
      "ProcessLabel": "system_u:system_r:container_t:s0:c158,c440"
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Nice. Thanks a lot, I looked all over issue page with podman and could not find any mention and strace didn't help much :) Perfect!

Btw, you can delete from bracket to bracket with `d%` in vim :) placing cursor on the first bracket..